# why can I not get access to my DLL function

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, loading, name-decoration

I'm trying to load a DLL dynamically using `LoadLibrary()`, which works, however I cannot then get the address of the function in the DLL that I'm trying to call.

DLL function: (in CPP file)

```
_declspec(dllexport) void MyDllFunc()
{
    printf("Hello from DLL");
}
```

Calling code:

```
typedef void (*MyDllFuncPtr)();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    HINSTANCE LoadMe;
    LPCWSTR str = L"C:\\Users\\Tony\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\DLL Loading\\Release\\MyDll.dll";

    LoadMe = LoadLibrary(str);

    if(LoadMe != 0)
        printf("Successfully Loaded!\r\n");
    else
        printf("Loading Failed \r\n" );


    MyDllFuncPtr func;

    func = (MyDllFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(LoadMe, "MyDllFunc");

    if (func != NULL)
        func();

    FreeLibrary(LoadMe);

}
```

func returns NULL!!!

What am I doing wrong?

This is a Win32 Console project.

Comment: If you're dll is written in C++, then you need to match the C++ name mangeling. View the export table and look at the function name.

Or declare the function in the dll as extern C, which removes the C++ name mangeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void MyDllFunc()
```

Comment: In DLL is enough. So the name would be mangled correctly and you'll be able to get the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. __declspec(dllexport) pairs with __declspec(dllimport).

```
#1: In the DLL, declare the function's prototype with __declspec(dllexport).
#2: In the .exe, declare the function's prototype with __declspec(dllimport).
#3: Compile the .dll. You should also get a .lib file.
#4: Link the .exe with the .lib, and compile.
#5: Success.
```

When you use __declspec(dllimport) and __declspec(dllexport), you never need to touch the WinAPI functions for loading a DLL. dllimport/export does it all for you. In addition, you don't need to extern C anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your exported functions name's are being [decorated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx) when using [__declspec(dllexport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), you can reduce the decoration using [extern "C"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d%28VS.80%29.aspx), however, it will not fully undecorated the symbol, to do that you need to use a [def file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28VS.80%29.aspx) and export it as a named symbol, else you need to use `GetProcAddress` using the mangled/decorated symbol name, which is short when exported using `extern "C"`.

Comment: Great point, people tend to forget that many C compilers decorate names too.

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL is built as a C++ dll, it's functions' names will change. This is compiler dependent. I'd strongly recommend to make it a C dll (C interface + C++ guts). I don't have an example on me right now, but you should be able to find something on the net.